# apt update has two failed index files and I can't find anything on the web about what to do

Tags: linux, debian, apt, software-updates, apt-mirror

I'm updating one of my systems and I get an error which I don't know how to fix or what the problem is.

Here is the error:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://the.earth.li/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 46.43.34.31 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://the.earth.li/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 46.43.34.31 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

```
root /home/kristjan # apt update                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Hit:1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                     
Hit:3 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch InRelease                       
Hit:4 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-stretch InRelease                          
Hit:5 http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch InRelease                                                 
Hit:6 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                                            
Hit:7 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch InRelease
Ign:8 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch InRelease 
Get:9 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Get:10 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch Release [118 kB]    
Get:11 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main Sources.diff/Index [8,608 B]
Get:12 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages.diff/Index [8,608 B]
Get:12 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages.diff/Index [8,608 B]
Ign:12 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages.diff/Index
Get:15 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch Release.gpg [2,434 B]
Get:16 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main Sources 2019-02-21-2009.35.pdiff [10.2 kB]
Get:17 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main Sources 2019-03-27-2010.32.pdiff [471 B]
Get:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main Sources 2019-03-30-2008.27.pdiff [726 B]
Get:19 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages 2019-02-21-2009.35.pdiff [4,149 B]
Get:20 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages 2019-03-27-2010.32.pdiff [531 B]
Get:21 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages 2019-03-30-2008.27.pdiff [1,599 B]
Get:22 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main Translation-en 2019-02-21-2009.35.pdiff [5,483 B]
Get:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main Sources 2019-03-30-2008.27.pdiff [726 B]
Get:22 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main Translation-en 2019-02-21-2009.35.pdiff [5,483 B]
Get:21 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages 2019-03-30-2008.27.pdiff [1,599 B]
Ign:23 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages                                     
Get:24 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free Sources [79.4 kB]
Get:25 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main Sources [6,746 kB]
Get:26 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Packages [7,064 kB]
Get:26 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Packages [7,064 kB]
Get:26 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Packages [7,064 kB]
Get:26 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Packages [7,064 kB]
Ign:26 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:26 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free i386 Packages
Err:23 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 46.43.34.31 80]
Ign:26 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free i386 Packages
Err:26 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 46.43.34.31 80]
Ign:31 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free i386 Packages
Fetched 235 kB in 1s (125 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://the.earth.li/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 46.43.34.31 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://the.earth.li/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 46.43.34.31 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is the system:

```
root /home/kristjan # cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Here is sources list:

```
root /home/kristjan # cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# 
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _S
#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.4.0 _S

deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free

deb http://the.earth.li/debian/ stretch main non-free
deb-src http://the.earth.li/debian/ stretch main non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://the.earth.li/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://the.earth.li/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free

# Virtualbox Oracle
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch contrib


#Tor###########################97
deb https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch main
deb-src https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch main
# For the stable version.
#deb tor://sdscoq7snqtznauu.onion/torproject.org stretch main


########################### Backports testingittt
#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

**What is the problem here and how can I fix it?**

UPDATE:

I have **two servers both running Debian Stretch 9.9 and with the same debian servers for packages and updates but I can only update one of them**, this one gives me this error:

```
~↓↓$↓↓ apt update
Hit:1 http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch InRelease
Ign:2 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                                        
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                 
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease [94.3 kB]                                                                      
Hit:6 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:7 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease                                                                                            
Get:5 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]                                                                                      
Hit:9 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian stretch InRelease                                                                                    
Hit:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod stretch InRelease                                      
Hit:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                  
Get:8 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch Release [118 kB]                
Hit:12 https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org stretch InRelease                                     
Get:13 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main Sources [205 kB]                 
Get:14 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch Release.gpg [2,434 B]                                                       
Get:15 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages [492 kB]                                       
Get:16 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main Sources [13.1 kB]            
Get:17 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages [27.2 kB]                            
Get:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages [27.2 kB]                             
Get:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages [27.2 kB]                                               
Hit:21 http://repo.steampowered.com/steam precise InRelease                                                                             
Ign:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages                                       
Ign:22 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Contents (deb)          
Get:23 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main i386 Packages [494 kB]
Ign:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages                                         
Hit:24 https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-stretch InRelease                                
Ign:25 https://apt.jenslody.de/stable stretch InRelease                                                       
Err:22 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Contents (deb)          
  404  Not Found [IP: 46.43.34.31 80]
Get:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages [169 kB]       
Get:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages [169 kB]           
Hit:28 https://apt.jenslody.de/stable stretch Release                                    
Get:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages [169 kB]
Get:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages [169 kB]
Get:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages [169 kB]
Get:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages [169 kB]
Get:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages [169 kB]
Get:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages [169 kB]
Ign:18 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:36 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Packages
Get:37 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Contents (deb) [31.3 MB]
Get:38 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main amd64 Contents (deb) [31.4 MB]                                                                             
Get:39 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free amd64 Packages [78.3 kB]                                                                               
Ign:40 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free i386 Packages                                                                                          
Get:41 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free Translation-en [80.3 kB]                                                                               
Get:42 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,180 B]                                                                        
Get:43 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons [30.0 kB]                                                                           
Get:44 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free DEP-11 128x128 Icons [85.2 kB]                                                                         
Get:45 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free amd64 Contents (deb) [809 kB]                                                                          
Get:46 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free i386 Contents (deb) [750 kB]                                                                           
Ign:36 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Packages                                                                                              
Ign:40 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free i386 Packages                                                                                          
Ign:36 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Packages                                                                                              
Ign:40 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free i386 Packages                                                                                          
Err:36 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/main i386 Packages                                                                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 46.43.34.31 80]
Ign:40 http://the.earth.li/debian stretch/non-free i386 Packages                                                                                          
Fetched 44.7 MB in 13s (3,223 kB/s)                                                                                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://the.earth.li/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/Contents-i386  404  Not Found [IP: 46.43.34.31 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://the.earth.li/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 46.43.34.31 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here are other `list` files just for detail:

```
~↓↓$↓↓ ls -asil /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
total 36
1175229 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 18 09:52 .
1175056 4 drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 May 23 01:54 ..
1178126 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   67 May  2 08:18 linuxuprising-java.list
1178021 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   75 Jan 17  2018 microsoft-prod.list
1177218 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   70 Jul 12  2018 mono-official-stable.list
1176353 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  712 May 13 06:23 mysql.list
1178155 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  148 Jul 24  2018 steam.list
1178030 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Jul 21  2018 stretch-backports.list
1176782 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   73 May 18 09:42 vscode.list
```

Here is `sources.list` on the other server:

```
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free

deb http://the.earth.li/debian/ stretch main non-free
deb-src http://the.earth.li/debian/ stretch main non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://the.earth.li/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://the.earth.li/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free

# Virtualbox Oracle
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian stretch contrib
```

Comment: whats with the downvote, can you please leave a comment

Comment: Not sure if this applies --> https://www.freesoftwareservers.com/display/FREES/Fix+Outdated-Broken-Old+Repo%27s+Ubuntu+-+Debian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to both [a blog posting from the owner of `the.earth.li`](https://www.earth.li/~noodles/blog/2018/09/no-more-mirror.html) and [the official list of Debian mirrors](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list), `the.earth.li` is no longer claiming to be providing Debian mirror services. The announced time for this change was February 1st, 2019.

### So why might it still work for some systems and not for others?

Well, the owner of the system is free to change their mind.

Or perhaps they just didn't get around to fully shutting it down at the exact date specified in the announcement, for whatever personal reasons.

Perhaps they've actually kept the mirror for their own local use, but (as one of the stated reasons for stopping was the cost of disk space) they may have pared it down to only cover system architectures useful for themselves. For example, if they no longer use any 32-bit x86 systems and have no need for 32-bit compatibility, they may have dropped out the `i386` architecture but kept the mirror for the `amd64` one. (If the VMs that are working are all 64-bit systems, this might be the reason.)

Or perhaps they've implemented some arbitrary type of access filtering. For example, they might be now using some form of GeoIP-based blocking, and their (non-perfect) GeoIP database happens to list the IP of one of your services but not the other one.

### What should you do, then?

You should switch to using some other repository, just as the owner of `the.earth.li` said. Since nobody is now making any promises that `the.earth.li` will be kept up-to-date, complete and functional, you should assume that it might become out-of-date or stop working entirely with no further warning.

You can do it in several ways:

If you have it installed (or care to download the necessary few packages to install it manually), you can use the [`netselect-apt` utility](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/netselect-apt) to automatically pick a new official repository mirror for you.

Or you could switch to using [`deb.debian.org`](https://deb.debian.org/) in your `sources.list`, which should automatically redirect your package management tools to a repository mirror reasonably close to you.

Or you might pick a new repository from [the official list of Debian mirrors](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list) and configure it manually.

Or you might use a third-party sources.list generator. For example, this one: https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: Have you seen this one `https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/` very cool

Comment: No, I hadn't. Added.